# replace multiple values using ifelse

Tags: r, dplyr

Based on the code and data below how can I replace values in the date column with new values using `ifelse`.

Error:

```
Warning message:
Problem while computing `date = ifelse(...)`.
ℹ longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Data and code:

```
df = structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), date = c("1/0/2000", 
"1/0/2005", "1/0/2005", "1/0/2005", "1/0/2005", "1/0/2005", "1/0/2005", 
"1/0/2005")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

desired = structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), date = c("01/01/2000", 
"01/01/2005", "01/01/2005", "01/01/2005", "01/01/2005", "01/01/2005", "01/01/2005", 
"01/01/2005")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

df = df%>% mutate(date = ifelse(date == c("1/0/2000", "1/0/2005"), 
                                                   c("01/01/2000", "01/01/2005"), 
                                                   date)) # works if I run ifelse twice once for `1/0/2000` and once for `1/0/2005` without c()
```

Comment: Yep that fixed it thank you, what's the difference between `==` and `%in%`?

Comment: You may need  multiple nested ifelse or if it is to replace multiple elements with a single one, it would be `%in%` instead of `==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `case_when` instead of `ifelse`

```r
df %>% mutate(date = case_when(date == "1/0/2000" ~ "01/01/2000", 
                               date == '1/0/2005' ~ "01/01/2005", 
                               TRUE ~ date))
#>   id       date
#> 1  1 01/01/2000
#> 2  2 01/01/2005
#> 3  3 01/01/2005
#> 4  4 01/01/2005
#> 5  5 01/01/2005
#> 6  6 01/01/2005
#> 7  7 01/01/2005
#> 8  8 01/01/2005
```

Comment: This and your comment worked too. If nots much what's the difference between `==` and `%in%`?

Comment: The comment didn't work Ed, because `ifelse` won't correctly select the appropriate replacement from the vector of replacements passed to the second argument. However, the difference between `==` and `%in%` is best shown by example. Try `5 == 1:10` and you will get a length 10 logical vector, where all are `FALSE` except the 5th value, which will be `TRUE`. However, `5 %in% 1:10` returns a single `TRUE`. If you try `c(2, 5) %in% 1:10` you will get a length-2 vector of TRUE (one for each of 2 and 5). But `c(2, 5) == 1:10` will be all FALSE, because 2,5 is recycled to length 10 and never matches

Answer (score 2):

You could use `gsub`.

```
transform(df, date=gsub('1/0', '01/01', date))

#   id       date
# 1  1 01/01/2000
# 2  2 01/01/2005
# 3  3 01/01/2005
# 4  4 01/01/2005
# 5  5 01/01/2005
# 6  6 01/01/2005
# 7  7 01/01/2005
# 8  8 01/01/2005
```

Or more explicitly:

```
transform(df, date=stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(date,
                                                   pattern=c("1/0/2000", "1/0/2005"),
                                                   replacement=c("01/01/2000", "01/01/2005"),
                                                   vectorize=FALSE
))
#   id       date
# 1  1 01/01/2000
# 2  2 01/01/2005
# 3  3 01/01/2005
# 4  4 01/01/2005
# 5  5 01/01/2005
# 6  6 01/01/2005
# 7  7 01/01/2005
# 8  8 01/01/2005
```